# How to pass variables in c# to frontend

Tags: json, asp.net-core, rest, reverse-geocoding

I am using reverse geocoding to get a readable user address i.e country and region using a restful api. I want to display it on the front end and i'm not to sure how to pass it to the front end. I can parse the json response to my liking and get the data i need, i just want to display these two variables as one concatenated string. I have fields for Longitude and Latitude in the User Model. Maybe the variables are out of scope?

**Backend**

```
    namespace VescovererWebApp.Pages
    {
        public class AccountModel : PageModel
        {
            private readonly VescovererWebApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;
    
    
            public AccountModel(VescovererWebApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
    
            public User User { get; set; }
    
            public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
            {
    
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
    
                User = await _context.User.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
    
    
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"http://api.positionstack.com/v1/reverse?access_key={apikey}&query={User.Latitude},{User.Longitude}"))
    
    
                    {
                        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        
                        JObject o = JObject.Parse(apiResponse);
                        var region = o["data"][0]["region"];
                        var country = o["data"][0]["country"];
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(region);
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(country);
    
                    }
                }
    
    
                if (User == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return Page();
    
               
    
            }
        }
    }

**Razor page**

    <div>
        <hr />
        <dl class="row">
            <dt class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.Longitude)
            </dt>
            <dd class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User.Longitude)
            </dd>
            <dt class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.Latitude)
            </dt>
            <dd class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User.Latitude)
            </dd>
            
        </dl>
    </div>
```

i want to remove these rows and essentially just have one which displays the readable address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the property Address to the code behind

```
  public string Address {get; set;}
....
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
  {
.....
        Address= "Country - " + country +" Region "+region;
  }
```

and page

```
 <dt class="col-sm-2">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
 </dt>
 <dd class="col-sm-10">
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)
 </dd>
```